# enabling iframes on big commerce mobile template?

Tags: iframe, bigcommerce

My Current Big Commerce site (http://magicallyme.com/) uses iframes on non mobile devices. But when I download the mobile template and put it in the proper place and enable it, it shows up fine but the iframes arent there. Doesnt anyone know a fix on how these could be enabled? or are iframes not worth the hassle for a mobile template. Thanks.